# Android onActivityResult (from MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) does not get data on Galaxy S5

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am developing an application which among other things makes pictures. To take the picture I use:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
startActivityForResult(camera, 1);
```

My onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Image_Selecting_Task(data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Image_Selecting_Task(data);
    } else if (requestCode == 2) {
        Image_Selecting_Task(data);
    }
}

public void Image_Selecting_Task(Intent data) {
    try {
        if (data.getData() != null) {
            ....
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

In Galaxy s2, s3, tab3, works perfect, but Galaxy S5 I can not get the data.
However if I select an image from the gallery this works.

Comment: what is Image_Selecting_Task? what do u expect in data object?

Comment: https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil

Comment: github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil  this gives me the same problems. s3 s2 etc works perfectly. S5 don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try my code:

```
public class GetPhotoActivity
{
 private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 50;
 public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
 private Uri _fileUri;

    private void TakePictureIntent() 
   {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    _fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
   }

     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data) 
    {
    try {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                _imageView.setImageBitmap(DisplayRotatedPhoto(_fileUri));
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GetPhotoActivity.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Project_ID", _projectID);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }

  private Bitmap DisplayRotatedPhoto(Uri path) {
    String filePath = path.toString().substring(8);
    Bitmap oriented = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;
    int width_tmp = bitmapFactoryOptions.outWidth, height_tmp = bitmapFactoryOptions.outHeight;
    int scale = 2;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale++;
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFactoryOptions2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapFactoryOptions2.inSampleSize = scale;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bitmapFactoryOptions2);

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        switch (orientation) {
            case 2:
                m.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case 3:
                m.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case 4:
                m.setRotate(180);
                m.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case 5:
                m.setRotate(90);
                m.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case 6:
                m.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case 7:
                m.setRotate(-90);
                m.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case 8:
                m.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                m.setScale(1, 1);
                break;
        }

        oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), m, true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        return oriented;
    }
}

private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * Create a File for saving an image or video
 */
private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {

        _mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
    return _mediaFile;
 }
}
```

Comment: getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)   method please??

Comment: I have updated my post, please see now.
Also added DisplayRotatedPhoto method (maybe you will need it).

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. You should think about doing some kind of bookstore with this. Because I used libraries, I used pieces of code and none worked.
This works very well.

Comment: sorry I have a problem when I picture in landscape mode. make the toast  Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred..." Do you have any idea to fix this? THANKS

Comment: I add this in my manifest: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"            And now work perfectly.

Comment: Hi, yes, that is right, I have the same line in my manifest.
Sorry for the late respone.

Comment: As I can compress the image before it is saved on the device? I have a method that compress images. But I dont know where I use it